# Create Google Analytics event with R

Tags: r, events, shiny, google-analytics, shinydashboard

I'm trying to track how people use my shiny app with google analytics.

for that i strart with a reproducible exemple  [i found here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html)

the tracking work for classic messure but the two event "button" and "click" are nowhere to be found in google analytics so I assume that doesn't work that way anymore.

I also try GALOGGER same result user tracker works but not sepcial event. Is any one have a solution to creat event into google analytics with r ? thank you

Comment: Does everything else work?

Comment: @danlooo well yes it detect when i use the app a have the pageview the scroool, the first visiter... all the mesure that auto, but not the one I want to do. a go to see all event in "configure --> events" but no they are not here

Comment: i also try with the gtag function but no...